# Is possible to implement jqxDataTable's filterMode in CodeIgniter-Flexigrid?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, jqwidget

I love beautiful *jqxDataTable* advanced filter mode: [Live Demo](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxdatatable/index.htm#demos/jqxdatatable/javascript-datatable-advanced-filtering.htm)
For CodeIgniter-Flexigrid you can have a simply filter mode like in this [Live Demo](http://ci-flexigrid.sameershemna.com/countries)
I want implementing **jqxDataTable's advanced filterMode** inside **CodeIgniter-Flexigrid** like this:

[image]

I don't understand what code change because both jqxDataTable and Flexigrid are jquery based but *how do you choose correctly what javascript libraries are good for codeigniter?* 
 I don't want qxDataTable css style because I prefer Flexigrid layout

**jqxDataTable advanced filter mode have this code**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title id='Description'>In this sample, the jqxDataTable's filterMode property is set to "advanced".
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdatatable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/demos.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // prepare the data
            var source =
            {
                dataType: "xml",
                dataFields: [
                     { name: 'SupplierName', type: 'string' },
                     { name: 'Quantity', type: 'number' },
                     { name: 'OrderDate', type: 'date' },
                     { name: 'OrderAddress', type: 'string' },
                     { name: 'Freight', type: 'number' },
                     { name: 'Price', type: 'number' },
                     { name: 'City', type: 'string' },
                     { name: 'ProductName', type: 'string' },
                     { name: 'Address', type: 'string' }
                ], 
                url: '../sampledata/orderdetailsextended.xml',
                root: 'DATA',
                record: 'ROW'
            };
            var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, {
                loadComplete: function () {
                    // data is loaded.
                }
            });
            // create jqxDataTable.
            $("#dataTable").jqxDataTable(
            {
                source: dataAdapter,
                pageable: true,
                altRows: true,
                filterable: true,
                height: 400,
                filterMode: 'advanced',
                width: 850,
                columns: [
                  { text: 'Supplier Name', cellsAlign: 'center', align: 'center', dataField: 'SupplierName', width: 200 },
                  { text: 'Name', cellsAlign: 'center', align: 'center', dataField: 'ProductName', width: 200 },
                  { text: 'Quantity', dataField: 'Quantity', cellsformat: 'd', cellsAlign: 'center', align: 'center', width: 100 },
                  { text: 'Price', dataField: 'Price', cellsformat: 'c2', align: 'center', cellsAlign: 'center', width: 70 },
                  { text: 'Address', cellsAlign: 'center', align: 'center', dataField: 'Address', width: 120 },
                  { text: 'City', cellsAlign: 'center', align: 'center', dataField: 'City' }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body class='default'>
    <div id="dataTable">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**while a ci-flexigrid CI_folder\application\view\view.php has:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>CodeIgniter Flexigrid Countries</title>

<link href="<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url') ?>assets/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url');?>assets/flexigrid/css/flexigrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<?php /*<link href="<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url');?>assets/flexigrid/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />*/ ?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url') ?>assets/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url') ?>assets/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url') ?>assets/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url');?>assets/flexigrid/js/flexigrid.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">

    ::selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
    ::moz-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
    ::webkit-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }

    body {
        background-color: #fff;
        margin: 40px;
        font: 13px/20px normal Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #4F5155;
    }

    a {
        color: #003399;
        background-color: transparent;
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    h1 {
        color: #444;
        background-color: transparent;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
        font-size: 19px;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin: 0 0 14px 0;
        padding: 14px 15px 10px 15px;
    }

    code {
        font-family: Consolas, Monaco, Courier New, Courier, monospace;
        font-size: 12px;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
        color: #002166;
        display: block;
        margin: 14px 0 14px 0;
        padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;
    }

    #body{
        margin: 0 15px 0 15px;
    }

    p.footer{
        text-align: right;
        font-size: 11px;
        border-top: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
        line-height: 32px;
        padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
        margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    }

    #container{
        margin: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #D0D0D0;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<?php
echo $js_grid;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

function test(com,grid)
{
    if (com=='Select All')
    {
        $('.bDiv tbody tr',grid).addClass('trSelected');
    }

    if (com=='DeSelect All')
    {
        $('.bDiv tbody tr',grid).removeClass('trSelected');
    }

    if (com=='Delete')
        {
           if($('.trSelected',grid).length>0){
               if(confirm('Delete ' + $('.trSelected',grid).length + ' items?')){
                    var items = $('.trSelected',grid);
                    var itemlist ='';
                    for(i=0;i<items.length;i++){
                        itemlist+= items[i].id.substr(3)+",";
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "<?php echo site_url("/countries_feed/deletec");?>",
                       data: "items="+itemlist,
                       success: function(data){
                        $('#flex1').flexReload();
                        alert(data);
                       }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            } 
        }          
} 
</script>


<div id="container">
    <h1>Welcome to CodeIgniter with Flexigrid Demo!</h1>

    <div id="body">
        <table id="flex1" style="display:none"></table>
    </div>

    <p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Which of this jqxDataTable javascript must i eliminate or edit to allow to codeigniter to work correctly and and to keep the flexigrid css style/layout?

```
../jqxcore.js"
../jqwidgets/jqxdata.js" 
../jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"
../jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"
../jqwidgets/jqxdatatable.js"
../jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js"
../jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"
../jqwidgets/jqxdropdownlist.js"
```

Comment: You will need much effort to get two different application/modules/what_ever to work like one. 
You should probably need to edit every jqx JS file to finalize your need.
I just took a quick look of jqxtabs.js and if you search code for "addClass" for example, there is 52 results though those are not pointed to exact classes but to pseudo variables and depending part of code related to extended files and what ever not. If not in documentation there is no easy way.
Short answer, don't even try if you don't have adequate amount of time.

Comment: is there a easy solution - third party solution if i just want integrate **individual column filter** for flexigrid that works also server-side? *(my data is on mysql database)* I look also here for column filter but i don't like datatable layout https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html? is an easier way?